# Needles in a Haystack (Inverse wordsearch)

Tags: word, knowledge, word-search

Wordsearch with a little twist.

There are 22 words hidden inside the grid (purposely), they are all:

> 1) Characters from fiction books
>
> 2) Countries in South America
>
> 3) Ex-Presidents of the US

[image]

Find as many words as possible for the word list. Words can be in any direction.

There will very likely have to be some sharing of answers, as it is very unlikely one person will know them all, so make sure to give credit if some of your words were discovered by others.
This will probably be difficult but maybe it will work...

For formatting your answer, you could write where the clues are for example: Example(4,5,NE), where (4, 5) is the first letter coordinate and NE is the direction.

Comment: "*Characters from fiction books*" - if Rand al'Thor isn't in there, I'll be disappointed :-P

Comment: No hints but you may be pleasantly suprised ;)

Comment: @randal'thor I see Egwene al'Vere on the 5th line (backwards)...

Comment: I even saw "gwene alvere" and I was very confused because it looked like a name

Comment: @dcfyj Full confession:  I googled "Gwen Ealvere", thinking it was a character name, and Google told me I must be looking for Egwene al'Vere.

Comment: I did the same, Google wasn't as kind to me

Comment: All that aside - (11,16) W is "RAND".  Close enough. :)

Comment: Do the remaining letters have a special meaning like in most of this kind of games?

Comment: @FrodCube no, there is just one more word that hasn't been found yet.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Awww, and there I was thinking you were a fellow WoT fan :-(

Comment: @randal'thor I keep thinking I should read (I think I'd enjoy it), but have never gotten around to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: solved grid]

```
    Row,Col Dir Cat   Word found              More info
    --- --- --- ----  ----------              ---------
1   (14,06) NE  Fict  Adrian Mole             Adrian Mole series by Sue Townsend
2   (04,11) W   Pres  Bill Clinton
3   (08,13) SW  Ctry  Chile
4   (14,15) N   Fict  Edward Hyde             Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde
5   (05,12) W   Fict  Egwene al'Vere          Wheel of Time
6   (01,17) S   Fict  Finrod Felagund         Silmarillion
7   (06,01) E   Pres  Gerald Ford
8   (06,01) S   Fict  Guy Montag              Fahrenheit 451
9   (07,14) S   Ctry  Guyana
10  (04,16) S   Fict  Jacob Marley            A Christmas Carol
11  (02,16) SW  Pres  James Garfield
12  (13,02) N   Pres  John Tyler
13  (04,13) SW  Fict  Lennie Small            Of Mice and Men
14  (12,18) N   Fict  Lyra Belacqua           His Dark Materials
15  (14,02) NE  Ctry  Paraguay
16  (08,06) W   Ctry  Peru
17  (03,01) E   Fict  Polly Plummer           The Magician's Nephew
18  (02,01) E   Pres  Thomas Jefferson
19  (07,03) E   Ctry  Uruguay
20  (14,14) W   Ctry  Venezuela
21  (01,15) W   Pres  William McKinley
22  (14,05) NE  Fict  Winston Smith           1984
```

Comment: @FrodCube I was waiting till we had them all to number them, to avoid renumbering.

Comment: It's so that new people know how many we have. Also we are only missing two words so it's not a lot of work.

Comment: @FrodCube Only one missing.  The OP edited the question to say there are 22, not 23.

Comment: I think this should be it.

Comment: Good Job everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Posting things when I find them (22/22)
**Finished**!

> Thomas Jefferson, line 2
>  Gerald Ford, line 6
>  Polly Plummer, line 3
>  William McKinley, line 1
>  Jacob Marley, column 16
>  Uruguay, line 7
>  Finrod Felagund, column 17
>  Bill Clinton, line 4
>  Paraguay, diagonal
>  Winston Smith, diagonal
>  Venezuela, last line
>  Guy Montag, first column
>  Adrian Mole, diagonal
>  Winston Smith, diagonal
>  Peru, line 8
>  John Tyler, column 2
>  Guyana, column 14
>  Chile, diagonal

Found by other people:

> Egwene al'Vere
>  Lennie Small
>  James Garfield
>  Edward Hyde
>  Lyra Belacqua

Comment: If you find new ones, please add them to the community-wiki post as well.

Answer (score 4):

Found so far:

> WILLIAM MCKINLEY (row 1)
>  THOMAS JEFFERSON (row 2)
>  POLLY PLUMMER (row 3)
>  BILL CLINTON (row 4)
>  GERALD FORD (row 6)
>  URUGUAY (row 7)
>  VENEZUELA (row 14)
>  GUY MONTAG (col 1)
>  WINSTON SMITH (diagonal NE) 
>  PARAGUAY (diagonal NE) 
>  JOHN TYLER (col 2)
>  GUYANA (col 14)
>  JAMES GARFIELD (diagonal SW)

Comment: If you find new ones, please add them to the community-wiki post as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial answer:

> [image: WordSearch]

So far I've found:

> Polly Plummer
>  Bill Clinton
>  Gerald Ford
>  William McKinley
>  Thomas Jefferson
>  Winston Smith
>  Uruguay
>  Peru
>  John Tyler
>  Venezuela  (MikeQ)
>  Paraguay
>  Guy Montag
>  Lennie Small
>  Egwene Al'Vere (GPR)
>  Finrod Felagund (FrodCube)

Comment: If you find new ones, please add them to the community-wiki post as well.